# How to use startsWith and contains within a List of String

Tags: java

i have this implementation that I need to check whether the version with x.x.x format is accepted based on accepted version in the list with just a format of x.x.

For example, if 1.3 is in the accepted version list. then 1.3.1, 1.3.2 or simply 1.3.x is accepted. As if 1.2 is not in the list then 1.2.x is not accepted.

```
 @Test 
 public test() {
     Assert.assertTrue(isVersionAccepted("1.3.2"));
     Assert.assertFalse(isVersionAccepted("1.2.1"));
 }

 public static boolean isVersionAccepted(String version) {
        List<String> acceptedVersions = Arrays.asList("1.1", "1.3", "1.5", "2.5", "2.7", "3.1", "3.2");
         
       // process
        
 }
```

Comment: I don't think you want to use `startsWith` here.  For example, `"1.11.0"` starts with `"1.1"`, but I don't think you want to mark `"1.11.0"` as accepted when `"1.1"` is in the list.  A better algorithm might be to check separately whether the provided value is in the list, and then check whether everything up to the last decimal point is in the list.  I'm happy to provide an answer if you can't work this out for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stream#anyMatch` to check if the input starts with any of the values in the `List`.

```java
return acceptedVersions.stream().anyMatch(version::startsWith);
```

Comment: As @Dawood suggested in a comment on the original post, `startsWith` is not appropriate for this task.

Comment: @JimGarrison Just answering the title: "How to use startsWith and contains within a List of String"